# What is the ideal buffer/packet size to send over the network?

Tags: c#, networking, buffer, networkstream

Right now i have an application that is sending a file over the network. I am at the stage i need to optimize the app so that the transfer speed is ideal.

I have a super professional looking graff showing my situation:[image]

Y - Sending time.
X - Buffer size.

The Y is the sending time, and the X is the buffer/packet size.
Has you can see, from my experiments i have noticed that if the buffer size is to small the sending time is to slow, and if the buffer size is to big the sending time is to high.
There is a sweet spot where the buffer size seems to be ideal. That is where i need help from some people that hopefully have more experience in networking.

Right now this is how i am sending the buffer.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPackets; i++)
 {
       if (totalFileLength > netBufferSize)
       {
          currentPacketLength = netBufferSize;
          totalFileLength = totalFileLength - currentPacketLength;
       }
       else
          currentPacketLength = totalFileLength;

       SendingBuffer = new byte[currentPacketLength];
       compressed.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, currentPacketLength);
       netWorkStreamVar.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, currentPacketLength);
  }
```

Right now the fastest sending buffer size i have encountered is **1024 * 256**. 
Question list:

**How can i determine that sweet spot?**(where the sending buffer size is ideal)

Is is determined by the file type?

Does it depend on my network configuration.

Is there an "industry" standard?

Comment: ideal buffer size depend on network speed, package size, current PC and many other parameters. So try set different sizes - 512, 1024 e.t.c. and find best size for your case.

Comment: Hmm since this is not a single computer program, will i need to right a algorithm to determine the ideal packet size for each time it tries to send a file?

Comment: probably might try to use package size to determinate buffer size (it does`t depend on file type) only size.

Comment: What do you mean by package size?

Comment: lets pretend you sending 10mb file/ of few files - then buffer size would be set to say 2048, then file with 200Kb size - then use 1024. But buffer size should not be to big though.